# Why the score changes after I add one utterance and deleted it, shouldn't it be the same?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

when I am using LUIS to create intents, I get a 0.53.

when I added one question, it changes to 0.82.

But when I remove the question, the scores did not go back to 0.53, but to 0.62.

Is it normal for LUIS to act like this?

Answer (score 0):

Scores are not absolute, and only have meaning relative to other scores in the same request. 
LUIS training is nondeterministic, so between versions, and even between exporting and reimporting the exact same version of the app, an application and its models will not necesssarily return the exact same scores.
Your system should use the highest scoring intent regardless of its value. For example, a score below 0.5 does not necessarily mean that LUIS has low confidence. Providing more training data can help increase the score of the most-likely intent.